Navegacion entre pantallas sin utilizar onPressed flutter
una consulta se puede realizar una navegación sin utilizar el TextButton mediante la funcion de Navigator On Pressed es decir me llega la informacóon en el If y automaticamente se me redireccione a otra page enviando la inforamcion traida?. Adjunto codigo.
if (result != null)

TextButton(onPressed: () async {
 
 var resp = await gtxController.generaInfo(doc: result!.code.toString().trim());
 
 if (resp["status"] == "ok") {
 Navigator.pushReplacement(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ingresoMontoPage(info1Controller, info2Controller, info3Controller,info4Controller),
     ),
     );


Se puede realizar sin utilizar el TextButton, en tu ejemplo con la condición if (result != null) ejecutarías la función Navigator-
if (result != null) {
  var resp = await gtxController.generaInfo(doc: result!.code.toString().trim());    
  if (resp["status"] == "ok") {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => ingresoMontoPage(
          info1Controller, 
          info2Controller, 
          info3Controller, 
          info4Controller,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

